# Improved User Experience with SharePoint Upgrade

Tags: 2013, 2010, user-experience, productivity

I am looking for a white-paper or other type of testimonial document that describes real-world improvements in user productivity or satisfaction levels after upgrading from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 an/or 2016.  This information will being used to help justify our own upgrade plans to senior management in my organization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you will get that kind of thing. But I can tell you couple of things which we did to get approval. Basically we build a POC farm in sp16 and migrated the one site collection over there with fully 16 mode.then we present the comparison between current and future farm.we focus on following things

1. User interface(how responsive it is)
2. New sharing method
3. Sharepoint boundaries
4. Performance
5. search improvement
6. Workflow manager integration and advantages
7. OOS connectivity and usage
8. Data loss protection feature
9. New social features
10. Durable links
11. Hybrid functionality
12. MinRole topology
13. Zero down patching

You can pick the features you are currently using and create same in 2016 and present as comparison to convince them.